# An ODE has no solution of this form

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the ODE

$
Y'(t)=AY(t)+e^{\lambda t} v.
$

where $v$ is an eigenvavector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Also A has n distinct eigenvalues. I want to show that there exist no solution of the form $e^{\lambda t} w$ for $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

To do this I assume for contradiction that $y(t)=e^{\lambda t} w$. Hence

$
e^{\lambda t} w\lambda=Aw e^{\lambda t} +e^{\lambda t} v
$

which implies $0=Aw+v-w\lambda$ but I can not get any furthat than this. Any ideas?

Comment: It seams that you have e typo in the derivative $y'$ that is a derivative with respect to $t$ I suppose.

Comment: ty! it has been changed.

Comment: I've fixed. It's so?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You have $$(A-\lambda)w=-v.$$Say $\lambda=\lambda_1$, $v=v_1$, where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues with eigenvectors $v_j$. Note that the $v_j$ form a basis for $\Bbb R^n$, and in particular they are independent. Write $$w=c_1v_1+\dots+c_nv_n;$$calculate $(A-\lambda_1)w$ and you get a contradiction.

Comment: that's a good hint. what i get is $(A-\lambda_1)w=c_1Av_1+...+c_nAv_n-\lambda_1w=c_1 \lambda_1 v_1+...+c_n \lambda_n v_n - \lambda_1 w $  but I don't have the argument to say that this is not $-v_1$

Comment: Well at the end of that calculation you have that $\lambda_1w$. You want to substitute $w=c_1v_1+\dots c_nv_n$ for _that_ $w$ as well!

Comment: ah ofc I see. thank you very much.